# How to handle questions that should be closed as "need more focus" if you find dupes that answers one of the questions

Tags: discussion, support, duplicate-questions, close-reasons, needs-more-focus

Suppose that you find a question that contains multiple questions. For instance:

> Hi I have a few questions for my homework
>
> 1. How big is the stack size by default on Windows, Mac and Linux?
> 2. What is the difference between the heap and the stack?
> 3. Can I assume that `int` is at least 32 bit?

Granted, this question is not good at all since it's basically just a homework dump. But that's not the point. Suppose I find a good duplicate for one of the questions. Would it be ok to edit the question to only include the question that you found a duplicate and then close as duplicate? Or should you *always* just close them as "needs more focus"?

I was thinking like this. Provided that the sub questions are good enough on their own, the above example should be posted as three separate questions. If I edit two of them out and dup close, then there are only two left. I cannot really see the harm, since the splitting should be done anyway.

But also, maybe it's just not worth spending the time doing it.

Comment: I would just close as needing more focus.  Let the OP do the work of splitting it up.  You do it, and only provide one answer via a dupe close, then it will be 'your fault' that the other two questions remain unanswered and so 'your fault' that the OP cannot hand in a complete assignment.

Comment: @MartinJames Well, but OP can always post new questions.

Comment: Not if they're rate-limited from all those bad questions.(But I agree with @MartinJames.)

Answer (score 9):

I would just close it as *needs more focus*  and let OP do the work of editing the question into different focused questions. At some point any of those focused questions can be closed as duplicate if there is a suitable duplicate.

Let's not build an expectation that anyone can ask a broad question with multiple different questions in it and someone will be there to edit it.

Answer (score 6):

The purpose of closing as duplicate is to turn an otherwise good Q into a signpost to an existing answer.

If a posted Q is close-worthy for other reasons, just close it (not as a dup).  Doesn't matter if it's been asked before.

Comment: Opinions will differ on this philosophy. I like to think that closing as dup also helps educate OP to try researching more before asking.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the question will help people searching on Google to solve a problem, I will vote to close the question choosing one of the "close for low quality" reason, I will also down vote the question so other people are less likely to see it.

In addition I am likely to vote down all the answers, as people who answer low quality questions make the site less useful by rewarding people who ask low quality question.   However I may leave a comment pointing to the duplicate.

Comment: Yes.  It's especially annoying when the answer is in the tag FAQ:.   It grates to spend rep on downvoting mega-dupe answers from cucumbers with the massive rep they have accumulated from fruit that is hanging so low that it's fell off and seeded a new tree:(